# Reusable child states with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router for application state management with AngularJS. I have one particular set of states that appears as a modal in many places throughout the application. The `.modal` state is an abstract parent state, and there are several tab states that are children of that: `.modal.tab1`, `.modal.tab2`, etc.

My current implementation requires duplicating all of the modal states in my `$stateProvider`, like so:

```
main (/)
  main.page1 (/page1)
    main.page1.modal (abstract)
      main.page1.modal.tab1 (/page1/modal/tab1)
      main.page1.modal.tab2 (/page1/modal/tab2)
      main.page1.modal.tab3 (/page1/modal/tab3)
      main.page1.modal.tab4 (/page1/modal/tab4)
      ...
  main.page2 (/page2)
    main.page2.modal (abstract)
      main.page2.modal.tab1 (/page2/modal/tab1)
      main.page2.modal.tab2 (/page2/modal/tab2)
      ...
```

This is the url structure and state inheritance that I want, because I want to see the proper content behind the modal when it appears. But, as you can see, every new page greatly increases the number of state declarations I need to make.

Is there any way to declare these states only once, and then attach them to multiple parents? Something along these lines would hypothetically be ideal:

```
main (/)
  main.page1 (/page1)
  main.page2 (/page2)

.modal (*/modal) parent:[main.page1,main.page2]
  modal.tab1 (*/modal/tab1)
  modal.tab2 (*/modal/tab2)
  ...
```

Is anything like this possible? Another thought I had was declaring all of the modal state configuration objects at the top of the code, then passing those objects to the relevant states in `$stateProvider`. It wouldn't *really* accomplish what I'm looking for, but it would at least reduce the amount of repeated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this approach:
 1. declare all tabs
 2. declare all pages
 3. Loop through each page and add to state and on each iteration of pages, add all the tabs to the current page

this way you'll have all the tabs added to all the pages

```
var tabs = {
    ".modal/tab1": {
        url: "/modal/tab1",
        templateUrl: "tab1.html"
    },
    ".modal/tab2": {
        url: "/modal/tab2",
        templateUrl: "tab2.html"
    }
};

var pages = {
    "page1": {
        url: "/page1",
        templateUrl: "page1.html"
    },
    "page2": {
        state: "page2",
        url: "/page2",
        templateUrl: "page2.html"
    }
}

for(var key in pages){       //loop through all the pages
    var state = key;         //state of page
    var options = pages[key];   //{url,templateURL} etc

    $stateProvider.state(state,options);   //add pages to states

    for(var keyTab in tabs){     //now loop through all the tabs and add to current page
        var stateTabs = state + keyTab;    // e.g. "page"+".modal/tab1" for page1 i.e. "page1.modal/tab1
        var optionsTab = tabs[keyTab];
        optionsTab.url = options.url + optionsTab.url;  //appended url to show i.e. "/page1/modal/tab1"

        $stateProvider.state(stateTabs.optionsTab);  //add each tab to page here
    }
}
```